# DNN error return to Site

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke, ssms

I am new to DNN and unable to browse or log into my site because it is showing "DNN error return to site" and even when I try to return to site, I am unable to do so.
What could possibly be the cause and how can I resolve this.

I am using DNN 7.0 and SQL Management Studio 2008

Answer (score 0):

There are too many possible reasons for this for us to be helpful. You'll need to look in the error logs in order to get a more specific error and then Google that error.

To view errors, browse in the directory to /Portals/_default/Logs and then view the most recent file that ends in .logs.resources.

Comment: This is the error message I got "DotNetNuke.Common.Initialize - The connection to the database has failed, however, the application is already completely installed, a 500 error page will be shown to visitors"

Comment: I was able to resolve it. The error came up because I was using an older version of the Newtonsoft.Json.dll file, but I have resolved this. Thanks a lot.